# Crossed vs. Nested Design in R

Tags: r, lm

I am trying to do an experiment where I use three treatments to make the tallest popovers. The three treatments are:

1. using refrigerated eggs/milk versus room temperature eggs/milk
2. mixing the batter by electric mixer versus whisking by hand
3. keeping the oven door closed the entire baking time versus opening it while baking

I recorded the final heights of the popovers as my response and used 2 categorical variables for each of the three treatments. Would this be considered nested? I used the below code but is this only testing the interaction between all the treatments? My goal is to make a nested design but is it actually crossed? How would I do this in R?

```
height3=c(3.75,3,2.75,
4.5,4,4.25,
3,3.5,3.75,
4.5,4,4.75,
3.75,4,3.5,
4.5,4.75,5.25,
3.25,3.75,4,
5.25,5,4.75)

eggs=factor(c("C","C","C","C",
"C","C","C","C","C","C"
,"C","C","R","R,"R"
,"R","R","R","R"
,"R","R","R","R"
,"R","R"))



mix=factor(c("W","W","W","W"
,"W","W","M","M","M","M","M"
,"M","W","W","W","W","W","W"
,"M","M","M","M","M","M"))

oven=factor(c("O","O","O",
"Cl","Cl","Cl","O","O",
"O","Cl","Cl","Cl","O",
"O","O","Cl","Cl","Cl",
"O","O","O","Cl","Cl","Cl"))

plot(height3~eggs/mix/oven)

summary(lm(height3~eggs:mix:oven))
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a crossed design (and a good one). Experimental design questions might be better on sister site [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

In R, a linear model of this with main effects and interactions is as simple as this:

```
lm(height ~ eggs * mix * oven)
```

The `*` tests interactions and main effects, while `+` is only main effect, and `:` is only interactions

Comment: Thank you! I am testing for the interactions, using the colon, but I am getting an error that says: (1 not defined because of singularities). My last row for eggsR:mixW:ovenO has all NAs. I looked online and it says that it has something to do with linear dependency? What do you recommend I do?

Comment: Hard to know without knowing what your data are or looking at a reproducible example, but try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7338155/2706826 Perhaps post another question asking for help specifcally on this problem if it's not helpful

Comment: How many replicates of each treatment do you have? If it's just one for each grouping (e.g. 1 cold eggs, battered, door open), then it's just not enough to do what you want

Comment: I only did one replicate of each treatment. How many replicates do you recommend I do?  And how would I input these replicates so I can analyze? I'm new to this website and I'm not sure how to input my R data...

Comment: That's your problem then. If you only have a single replicate you don't have enough information to distinguish signal from noise. The number of replicates necessary depends on the amount of variation in your system, which you now have some idea on given you've done a pilot study. Have a look at some introductory texts on experimental design. Quinn and Keough is one that comes to mind though there are many

Comment: I used the DOE option in Minitab and decided to use 3 replicates; this gives an 80% chance of detecting effects of 1.06 SD or more. They said this gives a moderate effect size. I believe this is sufficient since it's close to 1. I have the analysis done in Minitab but I have to calculate the experiment in R, I'm just not sure how to include the replicates.

Comment: OK. I'm no longer clear what question you are actually asking here - I don't think the title and question above relates to what you seem to be getting at here. Consider asking a new question as it's more likely to be seen than editing this one.